# What is an adjective to describe something that burns at a hot temperature?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, adjectives

I am looking for a phrase or a single word that describes something that burns at a high temperature, like in this sentence:

> His temper was volatile and {hot-burning}, like acetone.

"Hot-burning" is the closest thing I can think of, but seems clunky and incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

The [military has what they refer to as '**incendiary**' grenades](https://www.pica.army.mil/pmccs/combatmunitions/grenades/lethalhand/an-m14-incend.html), which are partially made from white phosphorus and burn at a rather high temperature.

From the U.S. Army:

```
[AN-M14 TH3 Incendiary Hand Grenade][1]
```

> The AN-M14 TH3 incendiary hand grenade is used to destroy equipment or
>   start fires. It can also damage, immobilize or destroy vehicles,
>   weapons systems, shelters and munitions.
>
> **The grenade filler burns at over 4,000 degrees Fahrenheit and can burn
>   through homogenous steel plate – even underwater.** Burn time is 30 to
>   45 seconds.

(emphasis on the last paragraph my own).

Answer (score 2):

There are many good answers but so as to provide a wider gamut I offer

**[Scorching](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/scorching)** which means both **very hot and** in this context **harsh**  it would generally be used to describe a person who is more than likely to verbally "fly off the handle" without using the more generic **scathing** that would equally fit but does not mean hot.

> His temper was volatile and scorching.

It is synonymous with hot-tempered, fierce and **[fiery](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/fiery)** q.v.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **incandescent**: Merriam-Webster defines it as:

> Definition of incandescent (Entry 1 of 2)
>
> 1 a : white, glowing, or luminous with intense heat
>
> b : strikingly bright, radiant, or clear
>
> c: marked by brilliance especially of expression incandescent wit
>
> d: characterized by glowing zeal : ARDENT incandescent affection

(see [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incandescent)).  It’s also idiomatic to say

> incandescent with rage

(see [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incandescent%20with%20rage)) so would work well when describing somebody’s temper.

To expand on this, one common use of the word **incandescent** is in relation to light bulbs.  Incandescent light bulbs comprise a wire filament (typically made of tungsten specifically because of its very high melting point) through which an electric current is passed in order to heat it to such a high temperature that it emits visible light. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescent_light_bulb) the filament reaches 2,000 to 3,300 K (3,140 to 5,480 °F), so potentially hotter than a phosphorous incendiary grenade.  Admittedly, the bulb is usually filled with inert gas to prevent oxidation, so it is arguable that the filament does not "burn", but it certainly reaches very high temperatures.

My hesitation regarding **incendiary** is that it is often used in relation to *starting* a fire (see, for example, the first definition at [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/incendiary):

> 1. used  or adapted  for  setting  property  on fire

rather than relating to objects which necessarily burn at high temperatures.  This is particularly true in its metaphorical uses (as in your example): an "incendiary comment" might be delivered coolly and calmly but is nonetheless incendiary in that it provokes, or is designed to provoke, a heated response.

As an afterthought, all this talk of fire makes me realise that another word to describe a hot-burning temper would be **fiery**:

> 2. intensely hot

(Again from [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fiery)).

Comment: This is not an answer according to our standards here because it contains no reasoning or explanation in your own words. Please read [this advice from SE’ss Community Management team](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11731/2085) and update this with your content.  We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks for the feedback, which I will bear in mind in future.  However, my answer goes beyond the dictionary definition by referring to the idiom and its particular relevance to the OP’s reference to temper.  Is that not explanation enough?

Comment: Yes, the bottommost part helps. I may not  have paid enough attention to that part. Still,  it's hardly all that much original content.

Comment: I think this includes sufficient content, and I applaud your inclusion of a linked dictionary definition (*plus* a further reference and link!), but I support @tchrist's concern about *original* content: we'd prefer more than just "you could use", "it's idiomatic to say" and "it would work well". For example, you could note that the OP will use the adjective metaphorically, and *incandescent with rage* is such a common metaphor that it's become idiomatic. I encourage your future contributions :-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the word 'flaring' or '[Searing](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/searing)' .

[Searing](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/searing) seems to fit the bill perfectly. It means "extremely hot or intense".

Though there are other words suggested here by others such as inflammable / incandescent / scorching, it is not appropriate to use it in your context because you want to refer to the temper of a person in reference to something that burns and not actually referring to the thing itself which burns.

Comment: It is customary on EL&U to include direct quotes from links where the content of the quotes is an important part of the answer. Stack Exchange wants the questions and answers to be accessible in perpetuity, but links sometimes go bad over time. Quoting directly allows the relevant content to be visible even if the link goes bad.

Answer (score -1):

> I am looking for a phrase or a single word that describes something that burns at a high temperature,

Practically everything burns at **high** temperature. Perhaps you meant something that will ignite at relatively **low** temperature (such as acetone in your example). To describe this, you could use any of the following:

> **flammable**
>   easily set on fire: *the use of highly flammable materials.*
>   *-- New Oxford American Dictionary*

> **ignitable**
>   Capable of being set afire, burning, or causing a fire.
>   *-- http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/ignitable.html*

> **combustible**
>   able to catch fire and burn easily: *highly combustible paint thinner.*
>   *-- New Oxford American Dictionary*

and finally your own:

> **volatile**
>   Evaporates easily. Sometimes also means flammable and/or explosive.
>   -- http://www.chem.ucla.edu/~harding/IGOC/V/volatile.html

Comment: I think the OP meant something that, when ignited, produces a hot flame.